# Front Flash Brightness iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, image, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I have been working on a project for a while now and I have come to one thing I want to really work out that I haven't been able to figure out.

In the application when taking a front facing picture, I would like front flash to actually make the picture brighter.

I am using a custom AVCaptureSession camera, it is full screen. Here is the code that does make a flash happen, just the picture isn't brighter at all.

```
//Here is the code for a front flash on the picture button press. It does flash, just doesn't help.
UIWindow* wnd = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, wnd.frame.size.width, wnd.frame.size.height)];
[wnd addSubview: v];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
v.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];

//imageView is just the actual view the the cameras image fills.
imageView.hidden = NO;
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {
    for(AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }if (videoConnection) {
        break;
    }

}   [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
        imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *thePicture  = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        self.imageView.image = thePicture;
 //After the picture is on the screen, I just make sure some buttons are supposed to be where they are supposed to be.
        saveButtonOutlet.hidden = NO;
        saveButtonOutlet.enabled = YES;
        diaryEntryOutlet.hidden = YES;
        diaryEntryOutlet.enabled = NO;
    }

}];

}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the alpha to 0 (transparent)?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, otherwise the white window stays white forever.

Comment: Why not just set the background colour to `clearColor`?  Are you sure that your white screen is timed correctly with your image capture?

Comment: @Paulw11 if I set it to clear nothing comes up on the button press. All this code is within the button press for the picture being taken. I have been trying to figure out the timing. I'm guessing the actual flash and the picture are happening at the same time. How would I make the flash go off before the picture is taken and processed?

Comment: See the method you are calling `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` - The capture is complete when the completion handler block executes, so set the screen to white immediately before you call this method and set it back to clear or whatever in the completion block.  Note that you will need to dispatch the screen color change on the main queue in the completion block.  Also you will probably need to dispatch the `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` after a delay otherwise it will execute before the screen color has updated

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't mean to sound lazy, but would you show that in an answer? So I don't mess that up many times. If not, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the screen to white before the image is captured, wait for the capture to complete and then remove the white screen in the completion block.

You should also dispatch the capture after a short delay to ensure the screen has turned white  -

```
UIWindow* wnd = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, wnd.frame.size.width, wnd.frame.size.height)];
[wnd addSubview: v];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *thePicture  = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.imageView.image = thePicture;
                [v removeFromSuperview];
            });
        }
        //After the picture is on the screen, I just make sure some buttons are supposed to be where they are supposed to be.
        saveButtonOutlet.hidden = NO;
        saveButtonOutlet.enabled = YES;
        diaryEntryOutlet.hidden = YES;
        diaryEntryOutlet.enabled = NO;
    }];
}];
```

Comment: So I added this to my program and I am getting an expression error in an IBAction below. I am going to go through and check if I am missing a bracket or something.

Comment: There was a closing brace missing for the `if (imageDataSampleBuffer !=nil)`

Comment: I am still getting the same error, now in this block of code. I keep going though the figure out where something is missing. I am getting _Expected identifier of '('_ and on the same line _Expected ']'_ . The line I am referring to is that last `}];`

Comment: There was also a missing }];